# Two laravel projects on one vps using Virtualhosts, but users don't see the right project

Tags: linux, laravel, apache, virtualhost, vps

Basically I made two different Laravel projects (not connected) that i'll call:

- Project A
- Project B
  And bought two different domains that i'll call:
- Domain A
- Domain B
  But I only have 1 Linux VPS.
  As you can imagine, Project A must be reachable via Domain A, and Project B must be reachable via Domain B.
  Both the domains have their DNS records pointed to the VPS correctly, that's not the problem cuz they work.

The problem is:
I made two different Virtual Hosts files, one for each project (i'll attach them below) and enabled the sites with `sudo a2enmod projectA.conf`  and `sudo a2enmod projectB.conf` and after a quick `sudo service restart apache2` this is what's happened:

Domain B points to Project B and works correctly. :)
But...
Domain A is a little bit different:
- For the users that were used to go to this domain kinda often (i'm talking even 2-3 times a day), they get as a response, Project B
- For the users that weren't used to go to Domain A, they get Project A (as planned).

I tried flushing DNS records of the PC, clearing cache of the laravel project, checking the records again, but can't find the problem.

Can someone please save my day?

Here are the files:

**ProjectA.conf      (Virtualhost file)**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerAdmin admin@domain1.com
    ServerName domain1.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/domain1.com/laravelapp/public

    <Directory /var/www/html/domain1.com/laravelapp/public>
       Options +FollowSymlinks
       AllowOverride All
       Require all granted
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

**ProjectB.conf      (Virtualhost file)**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerAdmin admin@domain2.com
    ServerName domain2.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/domain2.com/laravelapp/public

    <Directory /var/www/html/domain2.com/laravelapp/public>
       Options +FollowSymlinks
       AllowOverride All
       Require all granted
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

I tried flushing DNS records, re-editing DNS records of the domains, rebooting the router of the users that can't see the correct project on Domain A but nothing seems to work...

Comment: Inspect logs; is there something strange?

Comment: Could be browser caches since it affects only users that have used the site before.  Or 
DNS propagation.  That can take a while depending on the TTL your entries are configured for.

Comment: First, thanks for the replies!
Nothing strange on the laravel logs, but after clearing the cache of the browser, and even trying different browsers nothing changes.
I noticed that for some of the users that have encountered this problem, going to the domain with their phone (so different network, not using their wifi) the project works great and displays correctly.